# Deleted over 1,000 customers from my magento 2 backend- how do I get them back

Tags: magento2, customer-account

HELP!! I thought I was just deleting a few customers, but instead it deleted over 1,000 is there a way to get them back into the database- I use magento 2 platform
thank you SO much for help

merle

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic solution to restore them through Magento. You need a backup. If you don't take regular backups of your own, I would suggest contacting your host. Most managed hosting will include backup services.

Once you have a backup, you can either roll back to it (which means losing other data since the backup, like orders), or set it up on a new environment export your data from there, and import it back onto your live site.

Comment: OK well I contacted my hosting company and they restored the back up!! SO happy!! I did loose one order since it came in while they backed up, but I had printed it out before they restored- lesson learned- doube check everything you do before hitting delete all!!